# How to stop TabbedPage icon from shifting up when it is selected

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

I'm trying to build a navigation bar with that has 5 icons on it (each for its own page). The issue that I'm currently having is that whenever I click on one of the icons it moves it up a bit (sort of a pop up) while you have that page selected. I know it's probably some sort of property that has to be set to false but I don't know exactly which.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

XAML code for MainPage.xaml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:views="clr-namespace:StudioDen.View"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            x:Class="StudioDen.MainPage"
            BarBackgroundColor="#FFDA00"
            UnselectedTabColor="Black"
            SelectedTabColor="Black">
            <!--The last three properties set the colours of the bar to yellow and the icons to black-->


    <!--Projects view on the tabbed page-->
    <NavigationPage IconImageSource="ic_projects.png" >
        <x:Arguments>
            <views:Projects />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>

    <!--Events view on the tabbed page-->
    <NavigationPage IconImageSource="ic_events.png" >
        <x:Arguments>
            <views:Events/>
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>

    <!--Upload view on the tabbed page-->
    <NavigationPage IconImageSource="ic_uploadV2.png" >
        <x:Arguments>
            <views:Upload/>
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>

    <!--Process view on the tabbed page-->
    <NavigationPage IconImageSource="ic_processV3.png" >
        <x:Arguments>
            <views:Process />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>

    <!--Login view on the tabbed page-->
    <NavigationPage IconImageSource="ic_loginV2.png" >
        <x:Arguments>
            <views:Login />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</TabbedPage>
```

Image of the navigation bar with the 3rd icon selected:
[image: navBar_Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's something Android does by default. You can disable it by writing an [Effect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/introduction) for it.

Make sure you are using the 28.0.0.1 Android Support Libraries and are targeting Android 9.0 (Pie). If you can't, there is one (bad) [reflection trick](https://montemagno.com/remove-shifting-bottomnavigationview-android/) you could try.

Add this `NoShiftEffect.cs` to your Android project, and of course rename namespaces and other values specific to you project and solution:

```
using Android.Support.Design.BottomNavigation;
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;
using Android.Views;
using App16.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly:ResolutionGroupName ("MyCompany")]
[assembly:ExportEffect (typeof(NoShiftEffect), "NoShiftEffect")]
namespace App16.Droid
{
    public class NoShiftEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        protected override void OnAttached ()
        {
            if (!(Container.GetChildAt(0) is ViewGroup layout))
                return;

            if (!(layout.GetChildAt(1) is BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView))
                return;

            // This is what we set to adjust if the shifting happens
            bottomNavigationView.LabelVisibilityMode = LabelVisibilityMode.LabelVisibilityLabeled;
        }

        protected override void OnDetached ()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Now add another `NoShiftEffect.cs` to your shared project:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App16
{
    public class NoShiftEffect : RoutingEffect
    {
        public NoShiftEffect() : base("MyCompany.NoShiftEffect")
        {
        }
    }
}
```

And finally consume the effect in your `TabbedPage`:

```
<TabbedPage.Effects>
    <local:NoShiftEffect />
</TabbedPage.Effects>
```

Credits to James Montemagno and his post on it [here](https://montemagno.com/xamarin-forms-fully-customize-bottom-tabs-on-android-turn-off-shifting/).

Comment: I've looked at the code you shared from that tutorial, could you please let me know what "MyCompany" stands for in the example above?

Comment: It can be anything really, it's just used as an identifier. It's comparable to the namespace in .NET. If you have any plugins coming in that use Effects, this prevents any naming collisions. Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.resolutiongroupnameattribute?view=xamarin-forms